# Measure distance between objects in Archilogic editor

Tags: archilogic

I am using the Archilogic editor to create 3D models of building interiors.

How can I measure the distance between two objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is currently no dedicated feature within the Archilogic editor that really solves this problem.

The only workaround that you can use to receive measurement information is to either select an existing wall or place a new wall into the scene and use it as a measurement tool. You can always see the length, width and height of the selected wall in the menu on the right side.

[Use a wall to get measurement information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9Kul.png)